# Temporary file path permission denied Mac Xampp

Tags: php

I know that this question has been asked before but I have tried all the different solutions and none of them seems to work for me.

I am using Mac OS version `10.13.5` and Xampp Version `7.1.6`

My `PHP` path is correct to `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php`

`echo $TMPDIR` always point to `/var/folders/mq/wdlrpzr93m54rcl__b5hs1l40000gn/T/`

I tried to run the command `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/folders/mq/wdlrpzr93m54rcl__b5hs1l40000gn/T/` but I get the error message that `Operation not permitted`

I have also tried to set up `upload_tmp_dir="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/"` variable in `PHP.ini` but that doesn't seem to work as well.

I have also tried to [Disable SIP](https://www.imore.com/how-turn-system-integrity-protection-macos) and change the permission, but that did not work either.

Please let me know what else can I do to change the temporary directory path.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can define beforehand a directory that PHP does have permission to and then use

`$fileName = tempnam(<directory_you_just_made>);
$file = fopen($fileName);`

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Comment: Tried that as well. It gives me notice that it has fallen back to the system's default temp dir.